# Don't follow dependencies for specific module with Webpack and Babel loader

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I am trying to `import` a file that is generated by truffle.js, and Truffle generates the file to be used in Node and in the browser.

This causes Babel (or webpack) to try and load dependencies that are not present, and I end up with a bunch of

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dependency' in '/file/you/loaded'
```

**I just want webpack/babel to load the file exactly as it is. No transpile, no fancy build process.**

There is the following section in my `webpack.config.babel.js`, but I don't think it is working as I want it to

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader'
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out,it was actually really straightforward.

Referencing the docs here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/

I simply used the `noParse` rule to keep webpack from parsing the file

```
{
  noParse: function(contents) { return /filename/.test(contents); }
}
```